# Resizing JTextArea while using lineWrap

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, word-wrap

I want to create three `JTextArea` in my swing application.

Each `JTextArea` has a different size.

The first `JTextArea` should have 8 columns

The second one should only have 1 column

And the last one should have 50 columns.

My initial problem is that:

Whenever I type something, the `JTextArea`  will keep on re-sizing its width.

This has been fixed by `JScrollPane`, `setLineWrap(true)`, and `setWrapStyleWord(true)`.

So here's my problem.

Whenever I add `setLineWrap()` to a `JTextArea`, the `JTextArea` will be resized.

My first and second `JTextArea` have been resized to 12 columns.

I searched and found some solution but they use MigLayout.

Is there any way to add word and line wrap in `JTextArea` without resizing it (and ofcourse, without the use of MigLayout)?

What's the easiest way to set the columns of `JTextArea` with word and line wrap?

Comment: *"Is there any way to resize JTextArea with word and line wrap without resizing it.."*  Can you have your cake, and eat it too?

Answer (score 3):

> What's the easiest way to set the columns of JTextArea with word and line wrap?

You create the JTextArea with code like:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 50); 
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(scrollPane);

frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout which respects the size of any component added to it. The BorderLayout.PAGE_START will repect the height of any component added to it.

Scrollbars will appear as required what text is added to the text area. So the key is to use a layout manager (or combination of layout managers) that meet your requirement.